# Find specify string within 2 string in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

Hello, 

 I have file like this :

```
today#123 
2934
9236
monday 

today#12341
4246
58234
monday

today#456
7768
32347
monday
```

But in my file is around 200k+ lines, but it's made from section starting with "today" and end with "Monday"

I can easy separate one or all section with  :

```
awk '/today/ {show=1} show; /monday/ {show=0}' file.txt
```

But i can't find out how to find section with special string (in this case 7768)
.  Can anyone help me ?

1.) there is random number of lines in every section

2.) file is constantly changing (once or twice per day)

the result should be like this :

```
    today#456
    7768
    32347
    monday
```

Thank you.

Comment: `'/today/ {show=1} (show ^^ $0 ~ /srchTarget/); ...` ? Good luck.

Comment: it's not working :/ it's showing syntax error,   awk does not know  ^^, i try to use only one but no match :( 
  
and also sorry for bother but can you explain what should ^^ do in this ?? 

sorry maybe stupid question  but i am  a new and can't find any information about two ^^ in row only one ^

Comment: arg. sorry for the typo, `^^` should have been `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may also help you in same. I am setting a variable named `value` where you could provide any value which you want to look for and no need to change anything inside the code too, apart from variable named value's value.

```
awk -v value="7768" '
/monday/ && flag{
  print;
  flag=val=""
}
/today/{
  val=$0;
  next
}
$0 ~ value{
  flag=1;
  print val RS $0;
  next
}
flag && val
'    Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
today#456
7768
32347
Monday
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk -v value="7768" '  ##Creating a variable named value where OP could define its variable value which OP wants to search in any line.
/monday/ && flag{      ##Searching for a string monday in any line and variable flag is NOT NULL then do following:
  print;               ##printing the current line then.
  flag=val=""          ##Nullifying the values of variable flag and val here.
}
/today/{               ##Searching for a string today here if it is found on any line then do following.
  val=$0;              ##Assigning current line value to variable val here.
  next                 ##next is out of the box keyword of awk it will skip all further statements from here.
}
$0 ~ value{            ##Checking condition here if any line value is equal to variable value then do following:
  flag=1;              ##Making variable flag value to 1 or in other words making flag value to TRUE here.
  print val RS $0;     ##Printing the value of variable val with RS(record separator, whose default value is a new line) and current line then.
  next                 ##Mentioning next will skip all further statements now.
}
flag && val            ##checking condition here if variable flag and val is NOT NULL then do following.
'  Input_file          ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: THANK YOU !!! this works perfect for my purpose!! 
But , Can you also explain why ?

Comment: there is one think, awk showing  section starting with  "today" and second line is line with "value"  (ignore all lines between  "today" and "value")  then continue normally . 

But for my purpose it's perfect i need to know full string in first line starting with "today"

Answer (score 2):

Using awk :

```
awk 'show && c{
        if(show=$1==7768)print c;
        c=""
     }
     show;
     /monday/{
         show=0
     }
    /today/{
         show=1;
         c=$0
    }
    ' infile
```

Output:

```
$ awk 'show && c{if(show=$1==7768)print c;c=""}show;/monday/{show=0}/today/{show=1;c=$0}' infile
today#456
7768
32347
monday
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
today#123 
2934
9236
monday 

today#12341
4246
58234
monday

today#456
7768
32347
monday
```

Comment: Hello Akshay,  This looks really cool but it works only if the  string is in first line after "today" .   String can be anywhere between     "today" and "monday"  
and also can you explain why it's work (only for first line)? 
sorry i try to understand but it's not so easy for beginner :/

Answer (score 1):

You could write  a bash script say `recordfinder.sh` for this. It can look like below:

```
# cat recordfinder.sh
#!/bin/bash
exitfn(){
echo "Usage : recordfinder.sh <filename> <searchstring>"
[ "$1" -eq 1 ] && echo "Couldn't open file" && exit 1
[ "$1" -eq 2 ] && echo "No search string provided" && exit 2
}
[ -f "$1" ] || exitfn 1
[ -z "$2" ] && exitfn 2 
awk -v str="$2" -v RS="" '$0 ~ str'  "$1"

# ./recordfinder.sh filename 7768
today#456
7768
32347
monday
```

Hope it gives you some flexibility <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
                    sed -n '/today/{:a;/monday/{/\n4246\n/p;b};N;ba}'
                         ^     ^     ^    ^          ^    ^ ^  ^  ^
                         |     |     |    |          |    | |  |  |
dont print all lines-----+     |     |    |          |    | |  |  |
                               |     |    |          |    | |  |  |
if found start of block (today)+     |    |          |    | |  |  |
  then start loop with label (a)-----+    |          |    | |  |  |
  if found end of block (monday)----------+          |    | |  |  |
    then check if patterm (4246) found---------------+    | |  |  |
      if found, then print this buffer--------------------+ |  |  |
    break the loop------------------------------------------+  |  |
  load another line into buffer--------------------------------+  |
  and loop (goto label (a))---------------------------------------+
```

Test:

```
$ sed -n '/today/{:a;/monday/{/\n4246\n/p;b};N;ba}' <sample.txt 
today#12341
4246
58234
monday
```